# change the header style in calendar

Tags: flutter, dart, calendar, flutter-layout

Ive created  a calendar using the flutter_calendar_carousel package.Right now it contrains the defaultr header with 2 buttons to both sides to switch between months and in the middle is the name of the month

code,

```dart
class CalendarPage2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CalendarPage2State createState() => new _CalendarPage2State();
}

//days to be highlighted
List<DateTime> presentDates = [
  DateTime(2020, 11, 1),
  DateTime(2020, 11, 3),
  DateTime(2020, 11, 4),
];
List<DateTime> absentDates = [
  DateTime(2020, 11, 2),
  DateTime(2020, 11, 7),
  DateTime(2020, 11, 8),
];

class _CalendarPage2State extends State<CalendarPage2> {
  //present tile color
  static Widget _presentIcon(String day) => CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        child: Text(
          day,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      );

  //absent tile color
  static Widget _absentIcon(String day) => CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        child: Text(
          day,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      );

//defining a new event
  EventList<Event> _markedDateMap = new EventList<Event>(
    events: {},
  );

  CalendarCarousel _calendarCarouselNoHeader;

  var len = min(absentDates?.length, presentDates.length);
  double cHeight;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //adding events
    cHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      _markedDateMap.add(
        presentDates[i],
        new Event(
          date: presentDates[i],
          title: 'Event 5',
          icon: _presentIcon(
            presentDates[i].day.toString(),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      _markedDateMap.add(
        absentDates[i],
        new Event(
          date: absentDates[i],
          title: 'Event 5',
          icon: _absentIcon(
            absentDates[i].day.toString(),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    _calendarCarouselNoHeader = CalendarCarousel<Event>(
      height: 500,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      weekendTextStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      todayButtonColor: Colors.blue[200],
      markedDatesMap: _markedDateMap,
      markedDateShowIcon: true,
      markedDateIconMaxShown: 1,
      markedDateMoreShowTotal:
          null, // null for not showing hidden events indicator
      markedDateIconBuilder: (event) {
        return event.icon;
      },
    );

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Calender"),
      ),
      body: _calendarCarouselNoHeader,
    );
  }
}
```

the output of the following is
[image: output]

what I want the header to be is something like this
[image: expected header]

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code I used the same package

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_calendar_carousel/flutter_calendar_carousel.dart' 
show CalendarCarousel;
import 'package:flutter_calendar_carousel/classes/event.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart' show DateFormat;

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'flutter calendar',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Calendar'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  DateTime _currentDate = DateTime(2019, 2, 3);
  DateTime _currentDate2 = DateTime(2019, 2, 3);
  String _currentMonth = DateFormat.yMMM().format(DateTime(2019, 2, 3));
  DateTime _targetDateTime = DateTime(2019, 2, 3);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _calendarCarouselNoHeader = CalendarCarousel<Event>(
      showHeader: false,
      onDayPressed: (date, events) {
        this.setState(() => _currentDate2 = date);
        events.forEach((event) => print(event.title));
      },
      daysHaveCircularBorder: true,
      showOnlyCurrentMonthDate: false,

      thisMonthDayBorderColor: Colors.grey,
      weekFormat: false,
      height: 420.0,
      selectedDateTime: _currentDate2,
      targetDateTime: _targetDateTime,
      customGridViewPhysics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      onCalendarChanged: (DateTime date) {
        this.setState(() {
          _targetDateTime = date;
          _currentMonth = DateFormat.yMMM().format(_targetDateTime);
        });
      },
      onDayLongPressed: (DateTime date) {
        print('long pressed date $date');
      },
    );
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 30.0,
                  bottom: 16.0,
                  left: 16.0,
                  right: 16.0,
                ),
                child: new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                          _currentMonth,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 24.0,
                          ),
                        )),
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text('PREV'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _targetDateTime = DateTime(
                              _targetDateTime.year, _targetDateTime.month - 1);
                          _currentMonth =
                              DateFormat.yMMM().format(_targetDateTime);
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text('NEXT'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _targetDateTime = DateTime(
                              _targetDateTime.year, _targetDateTime.month + 1);
                          _currentMonth =
                              DateFormat.yMMM().format(_targetDateTime);
                        });
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                child: _calendarCarouselNoHeader,
              ), //
            ],
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: output]